What is the meaning of $X^*(T)_{\mathbb Q}$ here?
In the book Basic Theory of Affine Group Schemes by JS Milne, he uses the following notation in the below theorem :
"For a torus $T$, there exist (unique) subtori $T_1,\ldots, T_r$ such that $X^*(T_i)_{\mathbb Q}$ are simple $\Gamma$ modules for all $i$."
where $X^*(T)$ is the collection of group like elements in $k[T]$ and $\Gamma$ is a absolute galois group.
In the proof of the theorem he applies Maschke's theorem to $X^*(T)_{\mathbb Q}.$ So what exactly is $X^*(T)_{\mathbb Q}$?.

$X^\ast(T_i)$ is an abelian group, and $X^\ast(T_i)_\mathbb{Q}$ is the tensor product $X^\ast(T_i) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}$.
